# Is it possible to query for datetime ranges with the Stripe API?

Tags: json, api, http, stripe-payments

Using the [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api), I'd like to be able to query for date *ranges* or, failing that, dates that are *greater than* or *less than* some arbitrary date.

I know that I can query for something based on an *exact* date, e.g.,:

```
https://api.stripe.com/v1/events?created=1336503409
```

But I want something along the lines of...

```
# Search for events where `created` is greater than the epoch time: 1336503400
https://api.stripe.com/v1/events?created__gt=1336503400
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. From https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=curl#list_events

> **created**: A filter on the list based on the events created date. The value can be a string with an exact UTC timestamp, **or it can be a dictionary with the following options**:
>
> **gt** (optional) Return values should have been created after this timestamp.
>
> **gte** (optional) Return values should have been created after or equal to this timestamp.
>
> **lt** (optional) Return values should have been created before this timestamp.
>
> **lte** (optional) Return values should have been created before or equal to this timestamp.

So with curl, you can build a request like this:

```sh
curl "https://api.stripe.com/v1/events?created%5Blt%5D=1337923293" \
 -u ${YOUR_API_KEY}:
```

The *unescaped* query parameter is `created[lt]=1337923293`.

Comment: unfortunately it seems not possible in one call to have invoices between two dates (for example, invoices in 1 specific month)

Comment: it is possible `Stripe::Charge.all(limit: 100, 'created[lt]' => timestamps, 'created[gte]' => timestamps })`

Answer (score 8):

If you're looking how to do so with the [ruby client](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby), here it is:

```
Stripe::Charge.all(limit: 100, 'created[lt]' => timestamps })
```

Answer (score 5):

Along the same lines. You can achieve the same thing with the Python client like so:

```
import stripe
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

my_date = '1/31/2011'
my_timestamp = datetime.strptime(my_date, "%m/%d/%Y").timestamp()


stripe.Charge.all(created={'lt': my_timestamp})
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, from many days. Works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For those of us using the Go Api, both formats below works for selecting a range:

```
params := &stripe.ChargeListParams{}
params.Filters.AddFilter("created", "lt", strconv.Itoa(1592217599))
params.Filters.AddFilter("created", "gt", strconv.Itoa(1591612124)) 
i := charge.List(params)
```

---

```
params := &stripe.ChargeListParams{}
params.Filters.AddFilter("created[lt]", "", strconv.Itoa(1592217599))
params.Filters.AddFilter("created[gt]", "", strconv.Itoa(1591612124))
i := charge.List(params)
```